# Month-by-month baby name data

Tags: demographics, names

I'm looking for a database cataloging the number of babies born with the name "Isis" by month, along with the corresponding database for number of female births per month. Ideally, this data would be from a government source for an English-speaking Western nation.

I need this to be by month or some smaller time period, not by year.

Answer (score 1):

The go-to places for reliable data on baby names are official statistical authorities.

However, official statistical authorities seem to collect baby names according to the temporal unit of a year, and not in smaller time periods.

For instance, [here](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/birthsdeathsandmarriages/livebirths/bulletins/babynamesenglandandwales/2019) are some data on baby names for England and Wales; the [methodology](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/birthsdeathsandmarriages/livebirths/methodologies/babynamesqmi) states that the frequency of data-collection is *annual* (implying that data for, say, monthly periods are not available).

As regards [baby names in the U.S.](https://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/index.html), the [background information](https://www.ssa.gov/oact/babynames/background.html) likewise indicates that data only exist for a given year, and not for temporal subsets.

Comment: The ONS data release has a small amount of monthly data in table 5, but it's only the top 10 by month. It looks like although it is collected on an annual cycle, the underlying data does include date of birth - they just don't release very much monthly data.

Answer (score 1):

R / CRAN has a package "[babynames](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/babynames/index.html)". See below.

To get it:

- Install R.
- on the R REPL, type `install.packages("babynames")`
- answer some questions (default CRAN mirror etc)
- work with the data.

```
Package: babynames
Title: US Baby Names 1880-2017
Version: 1.0.0
Authors@R: c(
    person("Hadley", "Wickham", , "hadley@rstudio.com", c("aut", "cre")),
    person("RStudio", role = "cph")
    )
Description: US baby names provided by the SSA. This package contains all
    names used for at least 5 children of either sex.
```